# How to manufacture different sized micelles in nano -scale?

Tags: biochemistry, homework, biophysics

I am trying to answer [q5](http://tenttiarkisto.fi/exams/9605.1.pdf):

> **"How can you manufacture micelles in A) nanometerer -scale B) and in ten nanometer -scale?"**
>
> **My Thinking**
>
> > **Observations and some thinking**
> >
> > 1. Oil in water forms a micelle [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micelle), not making it soluble.
> > 2. Whey protein in Water forms a micelle or is this due to other reason? Protein folding with hydrophopic-tailed-and-hydrophilic-headed-particels? Is this micelle or not?
> >
> > **Required Vocabulary about one answer**
> >
> > 1. what is IVC?
> > 2. PLoS?
> > 3. "[E]xtrusion step" = some sort of burst?
> > 4. PCR=Polymerase chain reaction [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymerase_chain_reaction).
> > 5. monodisperse = A collection of objects that `"have the same size, shape, or mass."` (source
> >        [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodisperse)).

Comment: On your other question, you have listed your attempt at the answer.  Please expand the information you have started to collect [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/how-to-manufacture-different-sized-micelles-in-nano-scale#comment3157_2343) within the question to show what you have tried.

Comment: Seems to me that "formation" is a more appropriate term.

Comment: ...I wish I could read the biology articles also at home, irritating...have to try some sort `"ssh -XY"` -thing to get those articles [there](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=micelle+formation+sizes&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5), everything payware stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A key factor that determines the radii of a micelle is the [critical micelle concentration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_micelle_concentration). The other is the the hydrophobicity of the micelles which can be measured using the [contact angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle). A lipid nanoparticle has a minimum size on the order of 50 nm due to the surface tension of the lipid bilayer. However, micelles can be much smaller.

As for the creation of uniform nanoparticles, I am going to claim that what I say next can be in no way a reasonable answer to a HW problem. Why? Because the information is hidden in some obscure PLoS paper ([Stapleton and Swartz](http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0015275)) with 7 citations using IVC. Typically, micelles created for emulsion-PCR are created by vigorous mixing and followed by an extrusion step. However, this creates a polydisperse droplets. Alternatively, if you were to use a microfluidic device, then more monodispersed droplets can be formed. The control of droplet size can be achieved by varying the flow rates of the aqueous phase and the oil phase as well as changing the surfactant.

[image: Micelles]

Comment: ...I cannot understand the pictures. Could you somehow explain what is happening there? I added some open issues to the q to decipher this.